# Проблема с базой данных SQLite в приложении Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

В приложении Xamarin.Forms под Android для хранения данных используется база данных SQLite. Подключение к ней осуществляется через sqlite-net-pcl версии 1.5.231. Проблема заключается в следующем. Я удаляю программно все таблицы из базы данных. Запускаю программу из-под отладчика и заполняю таблицы какими-нибудь данными. Запускаю программу повторно и вижу эти новые данные. Но если происходит сбой при отладке приложения, то база данных самопроизвольно откатывается к состоянию, которое было в какой-то определенный момент раньше и содержит старые данные. Как заблокировать такой откат? Я не могу понять откуда программа вообще берет эту устаревшую версию базы данных, ведь ранее я удалил все таблицы из базы командой Drop.

Comment: Видимо при сбое транзакция откатывается, потому вы и получаете состояние БД до изменений

Comment: Когда вы только создаете прототип приложения лучше сначала не подключать работу с реальной БД, а пользоваться классом, кот. вам будет отдавать необходимые тестовые данные.

Comment: @tym32167 Т. е. вы хотите сказать что транзакция откатывает базу на несколько дней? Но почему тогда именно на этот момент, если после него база несколько раз корректно закрывалась? Все равно непонятно.

Comment: @Bulson И как тогда тестировать приложение? Оно фактически завершено. Но такое непредсказуемое поведение базы напрягает, хотелось бы понять что происходит. А если база также будет самопроизвольно откатываться при работе готового приложения?